# How do I download and save a file locally on iOS using objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, download, wget, local-storage

I'm new to Objective-C and I want to download a file from the web (if it was changed on the webserver) and save it locally so it can be used by my application.

Mainly I want to implement what `wget --timestamp <url>` does.

Answer (score 150):

I'm not sure what wget is, but to get a file from the web and store it locally, you can use NSData:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.somewhere.com/thefile.png";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
  NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  

  NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.png"];
  [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, is this blocking or not? I would assume that this one blocks.

Comment: @schystz if by blocking you mean synchronous, then yes it is.

Comment: Similarly, one might also be interested in `+[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:]`

Comment: it stores the whole file in memory? If so, it is not a good solution

Comment: I'm storing in `NSTemporaryDirectory ()` and can not play videos .mp4. It works perfect for audio and images

Comment: it now working code ... NSData file nil return...!

Answer (score 17):

NSURLSession introduced in iOS 7, is the recommended SDK way of downloading a file. No need to import 3rd party libraries.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.something.com/file"];
NSURLRequest *downloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
self.downloadTask = [self.urlSession downloadTaskWithRequest:downloadRequest];
[self.downloadTask resume];
```

You can then use the NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate delegate methods to monitor errors, download completion, download progress etc... There are inline block completion handler callback methods too if you prefer. Apples docs explain when you need to use one over the other.

Have a read of these articles:

[objc.io NSURLConnection to NSURLSession](http://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession/)

[URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44)

Comment: Will this work asynchromnously

Comment: It would be strange for a Network API not to work asynchronously. So yes, the NSURLSession API is highly asynchronous: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html

Comment: Handling the delegate part is annoying.

Comment: Use `[NSURLSession downloadTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:]` to work with a completion handler instead of a delegate

Answer (score 15):

I would use an **asynchronous** access using a completion block.

This example saves the Google logo to the document directory of the device. (iOS 5+, OSX 10.7+)

```
NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GoogleLogo.png"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Download Error:%@",error.description);
    }
    if (data) {
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"File is saved to %@",filePath);
    }
}];
```

Comment: `sendAsynchronousRequest` is deprecated as of iOS 9.0.

Answer (score 6):

I think a much easier way is to use ASIHTTPRequest. Three lines of code can accomplish this:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/path/to/my_file.txt"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

[Link to Reference](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#downloading_the_response_directly_to_a_file)

**UPDATE**: I should mention that ASIHTTPRequest is no longer maintained. The author has specifically advised people to use other framework instead, like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Answer (score 1):

Sometime ago I implemented an easy to use "download manager" library: [PTDownloadManager](https://github.com/exalted/PTDownloadManager). You could give it a shot!

Comment: Very nice of you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways:

1. [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
2. [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)
3. [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/)
4. [easyget](http://www.easygeteasy.com), a commercial one with powerful features.

Comment: is ASIHTTP still supported somewhere? The website advises use of something else: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: No. Don't use ASIHTTP. For a high level tool use AFNetworking instead: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking