# iPhone - UITableView reload on scrolling

Tags: iphone, performance, uitableview, optimization, memory

I've a `UITableView` and each `UITableViewCell` displays a unique `UIImage` which is fetched from internet. As we scroll the `UITableView`, cells are recreated and `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called every time to configure cells. So it loads `UIImages` again and again from internet and scrolling is not smooth.

The solution I found for myself right now is to create `NSMutableArray` of all those `UIImages` on `ViewDidLoad` then load images into `UITableViewCells` from that `NSMutableArray` which is for sure giving me smooth scrolling.

My concern with my own solution is that when I keep all `UIImages` in `NSMutableArray` and those all objects are kept in memory for as long as application runs, I am most probably making inefficient use of memory.

Is there a better, more efficient way to do this which gives me smooth scrolling as well as best memory usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache the downloaded images on the filesystem. When loading a cell, first ensure that a cached copy of the associated image is available, then load it using `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`.

Comment: Thanks... how to cache images on filesystem? Can you provide a link to API? Or if it is possible to explain how to do, please explain..

Comment: @Atif: Download it using `NSData` and write it to "disk". See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5323427/9990) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think this example will help you..
http://kosmaczewski.net/2009/03/08/asynchronous-loading-of-images-in-a-uitableview/

Comment: Thanks for the link... Its helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. You should go with array of image link instead of the image.
2. You should load image asynchronously so that it will improve performance of creation of the UITableviewCell.
3. Verify that you are using **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier**, it will give you the smoother scrolling.