# Adding a time stamp to an Objective C URL save as?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, timestamp

**[Coding was found here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323427/how-do-i-download-and-save-a-file-locally-on-ios-using-objective-c)
Hi all.
In objective C, I am trying to download a file from the net and save it, however I also a require a time stamp! dd'mm'yy format!
Can anyone help?**

```
N*SString*stringURL =@"http://www.somewhere.com/thefile.png";
NSURL  *url =[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData*urlData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if( urlData )
{
  NSArray       *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString  *documentsDirectory =[paths objectAtIndex:0];  
  NSString  *filePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.png"];
  [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}*
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I download and save a file locally on iOS using objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323427/how-do-i-download-and-save-a-file-locally-on-ios-using-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get a timestamp as a string

```
NSDateFormatter *inFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inFormat setDateFormat:@"dd\\'MM\\'yy"];

NSString *parsed = [inFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[inFormat release];
```

Not sure about the apostrophes, though.  There may be cleaner ways instead of using the `alloc` calls but this should work and won't leak.

Comment: `[NSDate date]` is an alternative.  No equivalent for NSDateFormatter.