# iOS file downloading library

Tags: ios, svn, download

In my iOS app I use HTML5 files as game levels. New levels will be added in the future, so I need to create a smart solution that will sync files on device with files on the server each time a new file is added or an existing file is updated on the server. Ideally it should work like SVN update. Is there any existing library that solves this problem?

Comment: Couldn't you just submit updates for your game to the app store?  It might take a week or two, sure, but do new levels really need to be distributed instantly?

Comment: There are a few examples of downloading a file from the web here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5323427/937822

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Downloading is not a problem, I just didn't want to reinvent the wheel, since the problem was already solved in different version control systems. But I guess I have to code this stuff by myself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a web service, you will have to implement it on your server [with your favorite language-framework ie: php-codeigniter, python-django, ruby-rails]

I recommend using JSON for simplicity.

on your iOS side, with iOS 5 you can use `NSJSONSerialization`