# Load an PDF file from the Internet

Tags: ios, pdf, ios6

how can I load an pdf file from an server in my apllication?
I find only descriptions who this works for a local pdf file.

Nils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download first the PDF file to local storage and then load it in your application.
Use the NSURLRequest, NSURLConnection classes to download the PDF file and then use your PDF framework to load the PDF file.

Comment: OK can you give me an example to download the pdf?

Comment: See the answers to this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323427/how-do-i-download-and-save-a-file-locally-on-ios-using-objective-c